Unable to structure properly SSR event and language switcher
I have a basic question about SSR in general. I come from experience only in CSR and I find it quite struggling to do thing in SSR at the moment.
I have a case exemple that I would like someone to help me solve in order to understand a bit better.
In the current case I have an Nx repo with an app and some lib and I would like to setup a language changer.
apps/src/service => a service related to this app in order to set the locale of the user
'use server';

import { cookies } from 'next/headers';

import { defaultLocale } from 'src/config';

// In this example the locale is read from a cookie. You could alternatively
// also read it from a database, backend service, or any other source.
const COOKIE_NAME = 'NEXT_LOCALE';

export async function getUserLocale() {
  return cookies().get(COOKIE_NAME)?.value || defaultLocale;
}

export async function setUserLocale(locale: string) {
  cookies().set(COOKIE_NAME, locale);
}

apps/**/HeaderLanguage => a server component on my app that I would like it to show a language picker and change the language when done
import { useTranslations } from 'next-intl';

import { LanguagePicker } from '~remo-work/shared/ui';

import { locales } from 'src/config';
import { setUserLocale } from 'src/services';

export const HeaderLanguage = ({ current }: { current: string }) => {
  const t = useTranslations('shared:ui.LanguagePicker');

  const languages = locales.map((locale) => {
    return {
      label: t('language', { language: locale } }),
      value: locale,
    };
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <LanguagePicker
        languages={languages}
        current={current}
        // this will not work in this current setup.
        onLanguageChange={(value: string) => setUserLocale(value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

libs/shared/ui/LanguagePicker => a standalone component that is reusable across multiple app that has the sole purepose of making a menu to display languages, and dispatch on change an event
'use client';

import {
  Button,
  Menu,
  MenuDropdown,
  MenuItem,
  MenuProps,
  MenuTarget,
  rem,
} from '@mantine/core';
import { IconWorld } from '@tabler/icons-react';

export const LanguagePicker = ({
  languages,
  current,
  onLanguageChange,
  ...rest
}: {
  languages: { label: string; value: string }[];
  current: string;
  onLanguageChange: (language: string) => void;
} & MenuProps) => {
  return (
    <Menu {...rest}>
      <MenuTarget>
        <Button
          variant="transparent"
          tt="uppercase"
          leftSection={
            <IconWorld style={{ width: rem(14), height: rem(14) }} />
          }
        >
          {languages.find((lang) => lang.value === current)?.label}
        </Button>
      </MenuTarget>
      <MenuDropdown>
        {languages.map(({ value, label }) => (
          <MenuItem key={value} onClick={() => onLanguageChange(value)}>
            {label}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </MenuDropdown>
    </Menu>
  );
};


Now, apps/src/service is related to the app logic, so it should be usable in the app scope only, apps/**/HeaderLanguage need to use translation and the cookies, so it should be usable in server only, finally, libs/shared/ui/LanguagePicker do some client interaction so it should be client component.
The issue in the above setup is that the server can't bind an event with the client, so I need the client component to be able to change the language, but my LanguagePicker is a shared component so it should remain dumb and not know "how to change the language". Also it can't use cookies since it's server only. it feels like a circle that can't be closed.
How can I connect the dot properly?

Set your cookies on the client inside your LanguagePicker, and they will be passed to the server on the next request. Here's an example package you can use to help set cookies: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies-next
